# How to extract questions from text using spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am working on a transcript dataset and I want to extract questions from each transcript using the `spacy` library! Now, it's not necessary that every question ends at "?". I can't think of a definitive pattern to match and extract questions! Is there any specific pattern that I can use to look for just questions?

Comment: Which languages? Only direct questions (Who is the president of X?) or also indirect questions (I would like to know who is the president of X.)

Comment: direct Questions! in your 2nd example, i am only concerned with the last part of the statement which is the actual question

Comment: You mean *... who the president of X is.* ? That is not a question, but a relative clause. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are only concerned with direct questions (=interrogative sentences), you can run the [dependency parser](https://spacy.io/api/dependencyparser) and then you can identify the syntactic structure of questions.

For example, for English, you can look for:

- inversion: `verb + subject + ...`:

  - *Is it raining?*
  - *Do you like movies?*
- wh-questions:

  - `wh-word + verb + ...`

    - *[Where] is Australia?*,
    - *[Why] do you like movies?*
  - `wh-phrase + verb + ...` (*which* is the determiner of the initial NP)

    - *[Which song] did you like?*

Obviously, there are some corner cases:

- *Who do you prefer is none of my business.*

Going into pragmatics makes the task harder:

1. you need to identify indirect questions:

   - *Tell me where Australia is.*
   - *I wish I knew where Australia is.*
2. you need to identify interrogative sentences that are not, in fact, questions:

   - *Could you open the window?*
   - *Do you really have to be so annoying?*

For more detail, see, for example, Karttunen: [Syntax and Semantics of Questions](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Elaurik/publications/archive/questions.pdf)